# Security features provided by umbraco 4.11.9

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, umbraco

I am currently doing R & D on Micrsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 integration with Umbraco 4.11.9 and also new in Umbraco.

my concern is how can I secure my CRM SOAP service access by umbraco website so it will provide great security.my website also integrate DIBs payment gateway.

looking for your answers

Thanks
Sandip

Comment: That's a pretty broad question.  Secure it as you would normally do, without thinking about umbraco.  Same remark for the DIB payment gateway.  You should try to be more specific with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create on wrapper WCF service of crm SOAP service. using that service you set your service model. and in Umbraco use that service as middle ware.